# Why is my navbar not working when clicked, only works when i right click and open link in new tab

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

To start i got modified this from a pre-made template. I set all the links to the proper pages, and i can get them to open when Right click and select open link in a new tab. 
But I cannot get it to open like it should with a left click. The `navbar` is ran by Bootstrap, and I have never worked with it before.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Home</title>
    <meta name="keywords" content="text,veteran,veteran computers,voc rehab computers,computers,vets,chapter 31" />
    <meta name="description" content="On our website you can find computers, accesories, and training for Veterans of the United States of America! " />
    <!--  PbD Template   -->
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!--<link rel="shortcut icon" href="PUT YOUR FAVICON HERE">-->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../Images/favicon.ico" />
    <!-- Google Web Font Embed -->
    <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,300italic,400italic,600,600italic,700,700italic,800,800italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="js/colorbox/colorbox.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href="css/templatemo_style.css" rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
              <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.3.0/respond.min.js"></script>
            <![endif]-->
</head>

<body>

    <div class="templatemo-top-bar" id="templatemo-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="subheader">
                <div id="phone" class="pull-left">
                    <img src="images/phone.png" alt="phone" /> 866-757-1221
                </div>
                <div id="email" class="pull-right">
                    <img src="images/email.png" alt="email" />
                    <a href="mailto:sales@performbydesign.com">sales@performbydesign.com</a>
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="templatemo-top-menu">
        <div class="container">
            <!-- Static navbar -->
            <div class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="navbar-header">
                        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        </button>
                        <a href="#" class="navbar-brand"><img src="../Images/ppd lccjpg.jpg" alt="Urbanic Template" width="150" height="90" title="Urbanic Template" />
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="templatemo-nav-bar">
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="margin-top: 40px;">
                            <li class="active"><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="sales.html" id="sales">SALES</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="Services.html">TRAINING AND  DEVELOPMENT</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="AboutUs.html">ABOUT US</a>
                            </li>
                            <li><a href="index.html">CONTACT US</a>
                            </li>

                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    <!--/.nav-collapse -->
                </div>
                <!--/.container-fluid -->
            </div>
            <!--/.navbar -->
        </div>
        <!-- /container -->
    </div>

    <div>
        <!-- Carousel -->
        <div id="templatemo-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <!-- Indicators -->
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                <li data-target="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                <li data-target="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
                <li data-target="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
                <div class="item active">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1 class="templatemo-slogan"><strong>Performance by Design</strong></h1>
                            <p><strong>Vets Serving Vets</strong>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <h1>Sales </h1>
                                <p>Performance by Design offers a wide variety of hardware and software options that will meet your needs</p>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6">
                                <h1>Training</h1>
                                <p>Performance by Design offers personalized one-on-one training and small group instruction</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="item">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="carousel-caption">
                            <h1>Ready to Order?</h1>
                            <p>Contact us today for a free quote or to receive a catalog of products and services</p>
                            <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-orange" href="Sales.html" role="button">Order Now</a>
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide="prev"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span></a>
            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide="next"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span></a>
        </div>
        <!-- /#templatemo-carousel -->
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <!-- 3 boxes for input -->
    <div class="templatemo-service">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="templatemo-service-item">
                        <div>
                            <img src="../Images/Military-Logos.jpg" alt="icon" />
                            <span class="templatemo-service-item-header">Vets Serving Vets</span>
                        </div>
                        <p>We have partnered with the Veterans Administration supplying adaptive technology for disabled veterans. Our services include delivery, setup, and a two-year warranty. Our highly skilled training and development department has implemented performance support solutions for global programs within the U.S. government. We have also designed and implemented one-on-one, classroom, and online learning applications for Department of Defense, Department of Homeland Security and the Department for Veterans Affairs.</p>
                        <div class="text-center">


                        </div>
                        <br class="clearfix" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- Start second box -->
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="templatemo-service-item">
                        <div>
                            <img src="../Images/cve_completed_s.jpg" alt="icon" width="150" height="153" />
                            <span class="templatemo-service-item-header">                                        Service-Disabled Veteran-Owned Small Business</span>
                        </div>
                        <p>Performance by Design LLC, a Certified Service-Disabled Veteran-Owned Small Business (SDVOSB). Performance by Design specializes in providing technology and training to the federal government.</p>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="http://www.va.gov/osdbu/verification/" class="templatemo-btn-read-more btn btn-orange">READ MORE</a>
                        </div>
                        <br class="clearfix" />
                    </div>
                    <!-- Start 3rd box -->
                    <div class="clearfix"></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="templatemo-service-item">
                        <div>
                            <img src="../Images/sam_gov.jpg" alt="icon" width="184" height="107" />
                            <span class="templatemo-service-item-header">System for Award Management</span>
                        </div>
                        <p>Performance by Design is registered with the System for Award Management database</p>
                        <div class="text-center">
                            <a href="https://www.sam.gov" class="templatemo-btn-read-more btn btn-orange">READ MORE</a>
                        </div>
                        <br class="clearfix" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    <span class="height30"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/Performance-by-Design-1018610118161626/"><img name="facebook" src="../Images/Like-us-on-Facebook.jpg" width="400" height="100" alt=""></a></span>
    <div class="templatemo-footer">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="text-center">
                    <div class="footer_container">
                        <div class="height30"></div>
                        <a class="btn btn-lg btn-orange" href="#" role="button" id="btn-back-to-top">Back To Top</a>
                        <div class="height30"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="footer_bottom_content">
                        <span>Copyright © 2016 <a href="#">Performance by Design. All ritghts reserved </a></span>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="js/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/stickUp.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/colorbox/jquery.colorbox-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/templatemo_script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- PBD -->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please create fiddle for your question.

Comment: Sorry Sir' I am not sure what a Fiddle is?

Comment: Use --> https://jsfiddle.net/ <--- and create a replica of our problem so that we can have a better look at your code.

Comment: [link](https://jsfiddle.net/alvaradof/cu0jx7n4/#&togetherjs=Jh8xLD2NQ1)       This is the first time using Fiddle, so I do apologize if it is not right.

Comment: What happens when you just left click a link?

Comment: Nothing it just stays on the same page.

Comment: Try removing the `carousel`, I think is getting in the way.

Comment: carousel is overlapping the navbar, that is why your click is not getting trigger on navbar.

Comment: Have you checked your console for errors?

Comment: Yes I had a few but I fixed them. I don't know what to do, other than go a different route with my navbar

Answer (score 0):

The Element

```
<ol class="carousel-indicators">
```

is overlaying your menu, therefore blocking you from cicking the links properly. At least in the fiddle it is.

Maybe the carousel itself does so also.

Disable the carousel to check if that solves the problem.
If so, just adjust your CSS accordingly.

Comment: Just removed the whole section of Carousel code, still did the same thing  :(

Comment: When I start your fiddle, open the developer tools and just delete the node  "carousel-indicators" it works like a charm.

Comment: Delete "carousel-indicators" from the source code, or from the bootstrap.css?

Comment: I just did deleted it from the live code represented in the dev tools. It is proof enough, that this is causing the problem. By the way: as your fiddle shows, your HTML is quite broken. To make sure, everything works as expected, it is a good idea to keep the syntax in order.

Comment: I may be doing it wrong, but I deleted the:                                             <ol class="carousel-indicators">
 <li data-target="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide-to="0"   class="active"></li>                                                                                <li data-target="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
<li data-target="#templatemo-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
</ol>           And I am still having no luck.

Comment: Please refer to https://jsfiddle.net/zj64yub3/ ... the carousel is gone entirely, the code is cleaned up. works just fine

Comment: Stefan Dochow, I am not able to see any changes made in the jsfiddle. It just shows the old code.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zj64yub3/2/  ... sorry for not having saved it properly the first time, but cleaning up the syntax errors and removing the carousel is something you also could have done by yourself